# Computer cannot boot to bios

Tags: boot, memory, bios, power-supply, hardware-failure

When I turn on my computer, it just goes go to a black blank screen. It only has an internal graphic card.

Upon further investigation, I noticed the fan intermittently stop and start again.
Things I have done:

- Removed all peripherals, ram, etc but the problem still persists.
- Swap with a working RAM
- Reapplied thermal paste
- Blow dust

Don't know if I should:

- buy a new power supply to test

Thank you.

Comment: Can you boot into an OS normally and just the BIOS doesn't work or does nothing work at all?

Comment: hi, sorry for my unclear question. Nothing work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

**Check if The power supply (PSU) is busted** - there is a way to test the PSU without connecting to a CPU- refer here:  https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-power-up-an-ATX-Power-Supply-without-a-PC/

If this fails - buy a new PSU
If not - proceed to next step

**The connections of the cables are not correct** double check all connections in the motherboard are correct (RAM, CPU fan, PSU, GPU, etc)

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect all cables from the system, most especially the power cable. Let the system sit for a minute, then just reconnect power, keyboard, mouse, and video, and see if it boots.

if not, try a new power supply. Resetting CMOS shall also help.